# How to convert XML into string in Wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

**Scenario**
I've a use case where I've XML tags as shown, I need to convert the complete XML as a single string but don't want to stringify them because it then converts the tags `<` `>`as `&lt;` `&gt;`

**XML**

```
<VERIFICATION>
  <USER_VERIFICATION>
    <USERNAME>XXXX</USERNAME>
    <PASSWORD>XXXXX</PASSWORD>
  </USER_VERIFICATION>
  <REQUEST_DATA>
    <TRANSACTION_ID>XXXXX</TRANSACTION_ID>
    <SESSION_ID/>
    <CITIZEN_NUMBER>160XXXXX</CITIZEN_NUMBER>
    <CONTACT_NUMBER>033XXXX</CONTACT_NUMBER>
    <AREA_NAME>khyber-pakhtunkhwa</AREA_NAME>
  </REQUEST_DATA>
</VERIFICATION>
```

**Question**

My question is how do I convert the XML to string without affecting the angle tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place them within a CDATA tag.

```
<![CDATA[YOUR XML]]>
```

Comment: ![CDATA[<VERIFICATION>
  <USER_VERIFICATION>
    <USERNAME>XXXX</USERNAME>
    <PASSWORD>XXXXX</PASSWORD>
  </USER_VERIFICATION>
  <REQUEST_DATA>
    <TRANSACTION_ID>XXXXX</TRANSACTION_ID>
    <SESSION_ID/>
    <CITIZEN_NUMBER>160XXXXX</CITIZEN_NUMBER>
    <CONTACT_NUMBER>033XXXX</CONTACT_NUMBER>
    <AREA_NAME>khyber-pakhtunkhwa</AREA_NAME>
  </REQUEST_DATA>
</VERIFICATION>]

Comment: This didn't worked

Comment: @AyubJamal you need to provide the full code you are trying so we can better understand the issue.

Comment: I tried again and it actually worked. Thanks